# how to create slideshow for string 64 type image in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble to create image slideshow. An image fetched from data base and binded into view model. it working fine. now i want to create slideshow with available images. i had tried like this.

```js
$(function () {
        function loop() {
            $('.slider .inner-wrap').fadeIn("slow").css('marginLeft', 0).delay(2000)
            .animate({ "marginLeft": "-200px" }, 700).delay(2000)
                .animate({ "marginLeft": "-400px" }, 700).delay(2000)
                .fadeOut("slow", loop);
        }
        loop();
    });
```

```css
 .slider {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 30px auto;
        background-image: url('http://www.thatssotrue.com/images/ajax_loader.gif');
        background-size: 50px 50px;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

        .slider img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

    .inner-wrap {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slider">
                                <div class="inner-wrap">
                                    <img class=" item-1" id="slides" />
                                </div>
                                </div>                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

this is how i had bind my images

```html
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    var imgid = i;
                    var imagetemp = "<img id='" + imgid + "'style='margin:5px;cursor:zoom-in;width:200px;height: 150px;' onclick='getid(this)' src='" + clubimage[i] + "'>";// onclick='getid(this)'
                    var slider = "<img id='" + imgid + "'src='" + clubimage[i] + "'>";
                    $("#image").append(imagetemp);
                    $("#slides").append(slider);
                }
```

My images unable to shows here. please help me. thankyou

Comment: how you build your clubimage array?

Comment: well for loop is like this

Comment: For(var i=0;i<clubimage.length;i++){}

Answer (score 0):

Finally i had achieved my slideshow in knockout js. complete solutions is here.
my ajax response. I had call swapImage() method in it.

```js
 success: function (data) {
                image = JSON.parse(data.imageResult);
                self.bindimage(image);
                for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                    var imgid = i;
                    var imagetemp = "<img id='" + imgid + "'style='margin:5px;cursor:zoom-in;width:200px;height: 150px;' onclick='getid(this)' src='" + image[i] + "'>";
                    var imgslide = "<li><img class='slides' style='margin:5px' src='" +image[i] + "'/></li>";
                    $("#image").append(imagetemp);
                }
                swapImage();
                if (data.imageResult == '"Invalid Connection"') {
                    alert("Invalid Connection");
                }
```

i had created javascript method like this.

```js
var i = 0;
    function swapImage() {
        var im = image[i];
        $("#imgslide").empty();
        var imgid = 'galimg' + i;
        var imagesilde = "<img id='" + imgid + "'style=width:500px;height:450px;'rel='alternate' src='" + image[i] + "'/>";
        $("#imgslide").fadeIn("slow", "swing");
        $("#imgslide").append(imagesilde);
        if (i < image.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
        setTimeout('swapImage()', 3000);
    }
```

And bind into HTML tag like this.using selector

```html
<div id="imgslide" />
```

Finally i got my requirement.